# Maven liquibase plugin change log file

Tags: maven, liquibase

Using `liquibase-maven-plugin` inside a project :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>some maven phase</phase>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>liquibase/changeLogFile.xml</changeLogFile>
                <!-- other configurations -->
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `changeLogFile` is in `/src/main/resources/liquibase`.
It works when bound to [any phase in the range](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) `validate` - `prepare-package`.
When bound to a later phase, i.e. `package` - `deploy`, it fails with the error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default) on project ...: **Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase/changeLogFile.xml does not exist**

It will find the changeLog file if the path is specified as `src/main/resources/liquibase/changeLogFile.xml` but that's beside the point.
Why binding the plugin to a later phase makes it fail ?